# How to load video into winforms from resources?

Tags: c#, resources, mp4

I want to add video file in my windows form application, the video format type is MP4. I already searched on how to add video and I found an answer to use windows media player library.

I used it but once I put the complete URL of my file, it works on my machine, but when I install it on any other, it does not play. I know the reason that I'm giving location of video which is my HD location, then I searched further and found embed resources, I do change build action into embed resources, but again having same problem.

How can I access my embed file within my code? I already tried the way like `namespace.file.mp4` or `namespace.properties.resources.file.mp4` but it says that:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'string'   L:\Project SciMult-calc\videotesting2\videotesting2\Form1.cs    29  41  videotesting2

Comment: Try posting some of your code because the error message you have is pretty clear to me you're trying to load a file into a string which will obviously not going to work.

Comment: Embedding videos as a resource is rather a bad idea, they are too large.  Getting an .mp4 to play requires a decoder that knows how to handle the specific video format, like AVC.  Not universally available, you typically have to buy one.  And easily verified by trying to play it with Windows Media Player.  Ask more about it at superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my brief code i want to play a video when user click "About" menustripitem

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

namespace videotesting2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"L:\about.mp4";

        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When you access the resource it is byte[] which is why you can't play the video.
Your method wants a path not a byte[].

You can write the resource to disk then play it.

namespaces needed

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
```

Something like this

```
//Place it in the directory of your application
string mp4Path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "mp4File.mp4");

//check if it hasn't been written to disk yet
if (!File.Exists(mp4Path))
{
    //write it to disk
    File.WriteAllBytes(mp4Path, namespace.properties.resources.file.mp4);
}

//play using mp4Path
```

Comment: this is my brief code , iwant to play a video when user click "ABOUT" menustripitem.

Comment: when i tried File.writeallbytes(mp4path,namespaces.prop.res.my.mp4 but after resource  my file is come as just by its name not complete with  extension .mp4is not comming why?

Comment: I think it's `System.Reflection` (without the s).

Comment: Corrected, sorry about that